# Programmatically Whitelisting Requesting URLs in Tomcat

Tags: url, url-routing, tomcat8

While I know I can utilize web.xml to allow or block certain urls for my web apps or globally, I am looking to do this programmatically.

Namely some simple regular expressions need to be added to a properties file, I need to read that properties file, and either accept or deny requests based upon matches of those regex's.

Where would I wire in that code to accept or deny requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end this is what I did:

1. Implemented an instance of `org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor`.   Of the three methods, I only needed to code `boolean preHandle`.
2. Added this line to my application context:

```java
<mvc:interceptors>
  <bean class="net.myurl.myapp.dashboard.web.interceptor.MyInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

3. Used the method `request.getHeader("referer");` to get the requesting server, and make a decision from there.  You can return false if you want Tomcat/Spring to stop processing, or true if you want it to keep going.

In the end it was pretty simple.

Comment: You can accept your own answer by now, seems to be a valid solution to me. Thanks for reporting back!